# PhoneGap iOS - Camera resizing only if photo bigger then targetheight / targetwidth

Tags: ios, cordova, image-uploading, cordova-2.0.0

I am using Cordova 2.0 with the built in Camera plugin.  My application contains a lot of photo uploading to a remote server, and I must constrain the size of the files phone-side for bandwidth and performance reasons.

I am using the following camera options for capturing new photos:

```
    var options = {
        quality : 30,
        destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        targetWidth: 1600,
        targetHeight: 1200
    }
```

This works great for photos taken by the phone as they are typically bigger then 1600x1200. When I upload an existing photo, however, I do not want to scale up images smaller then the target resolution:

```
    var options = {
        quality : 30,
        sourceType : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        targetWidth: 1600,
        targetHeight: 1200
    };
```

In reality I always want to avoid scaling up. Any ideas on how I can change the "scale mode" of the Camera plugin?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs,  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture, images in the photo library can not be scaled regardless of image quality.  Only when taken from the phone.

Comment: Actually it's only the quality they are referring to not being scaled. The images from the photo library will be scaled down/up based on targetHeight and targetWidth.